# how to expand a drop down list fully with angular material design?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have this drop down element.

How can i make if open fully? with no scroll?

I have tried

CSS:

```
.full-select{
   overflow-y: auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
<md-input-container class="hide-error-msg">
  <label>Filter</label>
  <md-select full-select ng-model="$ctrl.selectedSearchOption">
    <md-option full-select ng-repeat="option in $ctrl.searchOptions" value="{{option}}">
      {{option}}
    </md-option>
  </md-select>
</md-input-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following css rule:

```
.long-list > md-select-menu, .long-list > md-select-menu > md-content {
  max-height:none;
}
```

while specifying md-container-class on the md-select:

```
<md-select md-container-class="long-list" ...></md-select>
```

That can become pretty bad with large select lists so watch out.

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/Enqrmjqe4VNyE6l4dIcB?p=preview